# Libraries/Examples of Hover or Click Menus for web pages/apps, where to start?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, dhtml

I'm changing the layout of a web app that we are developing internally and have identified a few spots where a menu would be much more helpful than our currently layout. The project is currently built on Zend Framework and jQuery. Are they any good examples of context menus, or just menus in general that I should check out for inspiration? Are there any libraries out there that do a good job at this? Where should I start looking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Javascript drop-down menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101536/best-javascript-drop-down-menu)

Comment: I hadn't seen that when searching. I am not limiting this to JS only, as I would be fine with a good looking solution in dhtml/css/whatever. That thread however, is full of great info. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you would like css menus? Check [this](http://www.cssmenus.co.uk/index.html) resource.

Comment: +1: bancer this is very much along the style/reference that I am looking for.