# dropdown menu using JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Javascript drop-down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101536/best-javascript-drop-down-menu)

I want to have a dropdown menu bar in which onmouseover effect, the child of the parent elements of the menu`s come from database. Can any body help me how to do this. well, my thoughts are guiding me that this will possibly be done by a javascript and i am struggling doing so. Am i wrong with my approach of using javascript ? is there any other way of doing this? Well, can you people guide me how to do this?
thank you.

Comment: what technologies are you using? jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many examples available. like: 
http://www.narga.net/sexy-jquery-drop-down-multi-level-menu/

Preferable thing is to try out something and then post where you hit roadblock.

Comment: what if i dont want to use jquery ?

Answer (score 5):

Use  [Jquery ui auto complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).
If you don't want to use jQuery, then you can use JavaScript to create simple navigation. [Googling this](http://www.google.com/search?q=Creating%20navigation%20in%20JavaScript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-a) will give you many good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact problem I was trying to solve today.. Except I was trying to populate a form drop down, with results from database. In case you are not using a Javascript library, here is a quick solution.

Yes you are right that you will need to use Javascript and Ajax to do the query to the database(atleast thats one way).

1. Have a javascript function that handles the onMouseOver event. Gather the value that was selected in the menu and make an Ajax request. The ajax request may look like ajaxPostRequest(url, handler, post_data). Pass the value selected to that Ajax call in post_data, to a server side script- url and do the query there. Pass the results to the handler.
2. In the handler, check to see if the results were ok? If they are good.. make another ajax call and pass the results to your menu page. Populate the child menu with the results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Client Javascript won't fetch you the database values if you are not talking AJAX (which I wouldn't recommend for menu data). You fetch the values on server side, load them into HTML elements on the web page using server side scripting like jsp or asp. Then display them with the onmouseover Javascript function call or CSS psuedoclasses.

Comment: why not recommend using ajax for menu data? any flexibility issues?

Comment: No, not flexibility issues but it is relatively expensive to make AJAX calls that you could save on if you populated the menu data while the server was creating the response. Agreed?

Comment: i am a newbie .. i got you what you just typed but dont know the architecture.

Comment: That's alright. You mentioned you use ASP so some helpful links might be: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123.aspx, http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/menu.aspx

Comment: But take note, this is the part that fetches the data from database. You still have to render it somehow on the UI browser side. You can still use jQuery autocomplete as Bhanu mentioned.

Comment: ok.. but the problem is i have written javascript which is incomplete and dont know the way out.

Comment: @user286806 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2835/discussion-between-abid-ali-and-user286806)